# Updating a column in a dataframe with latest value from the latest year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Lets say I have a dataframe:

```
df = 
|ID  | year | value    |
|----|------|----------|
|123 | 2011 | Mango    |
|232 | 2010 | Pineapple|
|123 | 2022 | Orange   |
|232 | 2021 | Apple    |
|221 | 2021 | Banana   |
```

I want to update the dataframe value with the latest years value. I am expecting a final df as:

```
|ID  | year | value    |
|----|------|----------|
|123 | 2011 | Orange   |
|232 | 2010 | Apple    |
|123 | 2022 | Orange   |
|232 | 2021 | Apple    |
|221 | 2021 | Banana   |
```

Basically we want to update the values with the latest year's values.
So in this case, id - **123** is appearing twice in the same df. They both have different values **"Mango"** in **2011** and **"Orange"** in **2022**. We wish to have a new df created with same columns and same repetitions but with latest year's values.

I need this to be done **without using any loops** as the originial df is extremely huge and using any loop is taking huge time to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'Rank' & 'Merge' as below, gives required output

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123,232,123,232,221],'Year':[2011,2010,2022,2021,2021],'Value':['Mango','Pineapple','Orange','Apple','Banana']})
df['ID_Year_Rank'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Year'].rank(method='first', ascending=False)
df
```

This will add a rank == 1 to each row where year is latest in every ID
[image]

After this simple merge with itself based on filtered values give required result

```
pd.merge(df[['ID','Year']], df[df['ID_Year_Rank']==1][['ID','Value']], left_on='ID', right_on = 'ID')
```

[image]